# Button and input type search looks bad on different screens

Tags: html, css

I have text field and button Search. On my 15' notebook it looks good, but on other screens resolutions my button moves down or up towards text field and it looks bad. Could you help me? My code

```
 #searchinp{
    width:85% !important;
    height:50px;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:17px;
    color:#555;
    background:#f8f8f8;
 }

 .searchbut{
    background-color:#44c767;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:15px 31px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 50px #2f6627;
    outline:none !important;
    border:none !important;
    height:50px !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use ps for font size if you want to have the same look on different screen. It's preferable to use em or rem.

You also can create a container which contain your button and input and set a width on it.